# mysql drop statement with --

Tags: mysql, magento

What is the difference between drop table and --drop table in mysql

For example: I'm getting error if I use --  but in all other places of Magento they are using -- before drop.

```
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('faq/dinkchika')};
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$this->getTable('faq/dinkchika')} (
  `faq_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `faq_question` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `faq_answer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`faq_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use a white space after -- ,if you are not using whitespace after -- then it will not
count as comment.after whitespace your query will look like this.
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('faq/dinkchika')};
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {$this->getTable('faq/dinkchika')} (
  `faq_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `faq_question` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `faq_answer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`faq_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


");
Or you may use #(Hash) as well and 
Try this: Drop table IF EXISTS table_name;
And then continue with creating the table, as it will be guaranteed to no longer exist.
I hope it will help for you..
```

Answer (score 4):

A line that starts with -- and has a space after that, is treated as a comment until the end of line. It won't be executed.

You can read more about Mysql comment syntax here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comments.html

Comment: if it's a comment then why am I getting an error? I am placing that code in <?php ?>

Comment: your --query is not a comment because for comment you have to use a whitespace after --